# Is this the right way to filter a BehaviorSubject<object[]> with a another BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable, subject

I've been wondering around for hours on the web on how to filter a BehaviorSubject with a another BehaviorSubject and heard of switchMap so I implemented it. It works but, I wonder if there is a more proper way of doing it. TIA.

```
// results$:arrayOfObject and activeEntityFilter$:number are both BehaviorSubjects
results$ = this.flowService.searchAppResult$;

filteredResult$ = this.activeEntityFilter$.pipe(
  switchMap((activeEntityFilter) =>
    this.results$.pipe(
      map((flows) => {
        return flows.filter((flow: any) => {
          return activeEntityFilter
            ? flow.initiator_id == activeEntityFilter
            : true;
        });
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: It depends how you wish the `filteredResult$` observable to be triggered. With your solution using `switchMap` it'll be triggered only when a new value is pushed to `activeEntityFilter$` observable. In the solution by @NikhilWalvekar using `combineLatest`, `filteredResult$` will be triggered when either of the one source receives a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest)

The flow will be triggered when one of the observables emits new value.

```
results$ = this.flowService.searchAppResult$;

filteredResult$ = combineLatest(this.activeEntityFilter$, results$).pipe(
                        map(([activeEntityFilter, results]) => {
                            return results.filter((result: any) => {
                                return activeEntityFilter
                                    ? result.initiator_id == activeEntityFilter
                                    : true;
                            });
                        })
                    );
```

Comment: btw, Is there a way to have more than two observables? an alternative to combineLatest() for more than two observables?

Comment: Just found out that combineLatest can take more than two inputs.